# KQL - WorkDays - I would like to restrict the Query only of the Work Days from Monday to Friday

Tags: azure, kql

i have a Question about an KQL Query.
I would like to restrict the Query only of the Work Days from Monday to Friday.

How can i build this in KQL Query?

Thanks a lot.

A short Edit:

How can i build this in a existing Query with a Timestamp "timestamp between (datetime(06:00) .. datetime(15:00))" ??

For Example here the Code:

```
availabilityResults
| where timestamp between (datetime(06:00) .. datetime(15:00))
| where true
| where name == "warmup" and true
| extend percentage = toint(success) * 100
| render timechart
```

And now i would like only have an Result when is an Work Day

Best Regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

[dayofweek()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dayofweekfunction)

```
// Sample data generation. Not part of the solution.
let t = range Date from startofday(ago(28d)) to now() step 1d;
// Solution starts here.
t
| where dayofweek(Date)/1d between (1 .. 5)
```

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-10-05T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-06T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-07T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-10T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-11T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-12T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-13T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-14T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-17T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-18T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-19T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-20T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-21T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-24T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-25T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-26T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-27T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-28T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-10-31T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-11-01T00:00:00Z |
| 2022-11-02T00:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAy1OSwrCMBDdF3KHt0w2DRUEQdy5dtMTjGSSim2mpCOl4OFN1eX7P%20/R0zSPjEBKSJy5kD4kt7iJYqaikAgdGIuMr69impEVigsK5cS4kjJikQmLVr/EQJulJPZwCs5BBVlW66rKM7pwNo2vq/%202X2bBwIVrs5rmjXUH9dAmcWV%202n3A%20S7gzlqJDNuhbXF0H0hMRMO%20AAAA)

Answer (score 0):

Here The Solution of my Specific Answer:

```
Table
| where timestamp between (datetime(06:00) .. datetime(15:00))
| where dayofweek(timestamp) != time(6.00:00:00)
| where dayofweek(timestamp) != time(0.00:00:00)
| render timechart
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).